# Do we know the names of the vehicles/ships seen in The Last Jedi?

Tags: star-wars, spaceship, the-last-jedi

We got to lay our eyes on some cool new ships and vehicles in The Last Jedi in a couple different scenarios. We got some cool new speeders, more AT-ATs, the Largest starship we've probably ever seen as well as the scariest we've ever seen.

The ones that I've been wondering the most about are what I've been calling the:

#### Gorilla AT-ATs

[image: Gorilla AT-ATs]

#### Salt Speeders

[image: Salt speeders]

Some of the other new vehicles we'd seen was **Snoke's "super duper ultra" Star Destroyer**, which was the width of the entire First Order Fleet, and the menacing **Dreadnought** which featured at the start of the film.

Finally, whether we know the name of the bomber that the A-wings and X-wings were excorting?

#### Resistance Bomber

[image: Resistance Bombers]

Oh, nearly forgot:

#### Canto Bight Air Speeders

#### The walkers dragging the Battering Ram forwards

Comment: The dreadnought is probably the one described in the battlefront 2 single player campaign's expansion dlc.

Comment: @MarkRogers ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ I've not played or read anything extra, I've seen the film twice and didn't notice the names either time

Comment: The Canto Bight Air speeders might be the **[Cantonica Zephyr GB-134 speeder](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Cantonica_Zephyr_GB-134_speeder)**

Comment: @MarkRogers the image there and the helmet doesn't look _quite_ right.

Comment: Yeah, I haven't seen the movie yet so I can't say for sure.  But the wiki does mention it as appearing in the movie.

Comment: Also [Superlaser siege cannon](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Superlaser_siege_cannon)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The Incredible Cross-Sections book identifies them as;

- Gorilla Walkers = **All-Terrain MegaCalibre 6 / *AT-M6***
- Salt Speeders = [**V-4X-D *Ski Speeder***](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/V-4X-D_ski_speeder)
- Resistance Bomber = **MG-100 StarFortress Bomber / *B/SF-17***
- Dreadnought = **[*Mandator IV*-class warship](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Mandator_IV-class_warship)**
- Walkers dragging battering Ram = **All-Terrain Heavy Hauler / *AT-HH***
- Canto Bight Police Air Speeders = **Cantonica Zephyr GB-134 *Jet-Stick***
- Finn and Rose's stolen ship = **Guild d'Lanseaux *Custom Star Yacht***
- Snoke's Star Destroyer = [**Supremacy** (*Mega*-class)](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Supremacy?li_source=LI&li_medium=wikia-footer-wiki-rec)

Comment: The full name of the ski speeder is mentioned in the battlefront 2 game, feel free to rollback.

Comment: @MarkRogers - No, that's absolutely fine.

Comment: "MG-100 StarFortress Bomber" -- huh... going back to the series' roots there: the original space combat sequences are well known to have been inspired by WWII films, and that name is somewhat reminiscent of [a certain WWII aircraft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_B-17_Flying_Fortress)...