# Why was this left open at the end of The Last Jedi?

Tags: star-wars, the-last-jedi

Near the end of *The Last Jedi*:

> Leia is standing by the large door of the former Rebel base on Crait. The door is half-open. I can't remember the exact lines, but I think someone shouts "They're coming!", followed by Leia saying "Close the door".

Why did they leave it open in the first place,when they were expecting

> The First Order

to arrive at any moment?

Comment: I would argue that they left the door open to see the progress the First Order was making in their approach. It is possible that the radar equipment within the complex was still "booting up" and a visual confirmation of the enemy's approach is better than nothing. Either way, good for Finn and Co. or else they would have been bugs on a windshield...

Comment: @Odin1806 I did wonder if that was the reason (the base was old and decommissioned so the equipment might have been broken or require powering up etc), but then during the battle the door remains closed but troops are able to look out through windows and make it to trenches. Besides, they know the First Order is coming, not sure it matters _when_ they arrive. Maybe they were in the process of getting supplies inside? Would have been clearer if the movie had made that more obvious though.

Answer (score 6):

## She may have been waiting for the slow transports

It's possible they were wanting to see if any more Transports had been lost and were coming to the base late. However, as soon as they saw what they thought was the first wave of the First Order, they'd know that any surviving transports would now be dead, considering the First Order had over taken them. Furthermore, any reinforcements they called would need the door to be open to help them escape, so it's possible they were waiting until the last minute to close it.

Another possibility is that the closed door may hinder the base in some way, and after the destruction of Snoke's capital ship, they may not have known how much of his fleet had survived. Risking leaving the door open in case reinforcements come before the First Order seems practical.

I'm sure we will get more insight after the novelisation is released.